# css horizontal center images without using % percent

Tags: html, css

There are some **extra space** on the right side in my gallery...

My images' container:

```
.my-gallery figure {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}
```

Is it possible make images always horizontal center in different sized screen **without** using `% percent value`? Or someone has a genius idea that makes **extra space** not so weird?

Or `% percent value` trick is the only way?

In screen A:

[image]

In screen B:

[image]

```css
.my-gallery {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.my-gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 112px;
}
.my-gallery figure {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  width: 150px;
}
.my-gallery figcaption {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  min-height: 26px;
}
.my-gallery img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-gallery">
  <figure>
    <a href="big1.jpg">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/112x150" alt="1" />
    </a>
    <figcaption>111111111111111111111111</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="big2.jpg">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/112x150" alt="2" />
    </a>
    <figcaption>222222222222222222222222</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="big3.jpg">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/112x150" alt="3" />
    </a>
    <figcaption>3333333333333333333333333333333</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="big4.jpg">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/112x150" alt="4" />
    </a>
    <figcaption>444444444444444444444444</figcaption>
  </figure>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: What's the problem using the percentage?

Answer (score 2):

If using `%` is a problem, you could use css flexbox to get this done.

https://jsfiddle.net/76dybc3p/1/

Change css of `.my-gallery` and remove the float in `figure`

```
.my-gallery {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.my-gallery figure {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most practical approach is to use @media query

I also changed the `.my-gallery` rule to

```
.my-gallery {
  margin: 0 auto
}
```

Sample snippet

```css
.my-gallery {
  margin: 0 auto
}
.my-gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 112px;
}
.my-gallery figure {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  width: 150px;
}
.my-gallery figcaption {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  min-height: 26px;
}
.my-gallery img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 310px) {
  .my-gallery {
    width: 310px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 465px) {
  .my-gallery {
    width: 465px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 620px) {
  .my-gallery {
    width: 620px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="my-gallery">
  <figure>
    <a href="big1.jpg">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/112x150" alt="1" />
    </a>
    <figcaption>111111111111111111111111</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="big2.jpg">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/112x150" alt="2" />
    </a>
    <figcaption>222222222222222222222222</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="big3.jpg">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/112x150" alt="3" />
    </a>
    <figcaption>3333333333333333333333333333333</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="big4.jpg">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/112x150" alt="4" />
    </a>
    <figcaption>444444444444444444444444</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you wouldn't use %, but this is another alternative: use a table to scaffold your items and set the property table-layout: fixed;

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            1
        </td>
        <td>
            2
        </td>
        <td>
            3
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table{
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```